# Invalid Cast Exception When Reading Data From Excel In SSIS

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis, excel-interop, script-component

I am trying to read particular cell values of Excel and store in a table. But receiving an Invalid cast exception. Below is my code in VB Script:

```vb
Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Variables.FileName
Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
Output0Buffer.AddRow()
Output0Buffer.OrgName = oSheet.Range("A4").Value
Output0Buffer.UnitName = oSheet.Range("B6").Value
Output0Buffer.MonthName = oSheet.Range("A8:A19").Value
Output0Buffer.Goals = oSheet.Range("B8:B19").Value
Output0Buffer.Actual = oSheet.Range("C8:C19").Value
```

The Error Message is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'Object(,)' to type 'String' is not valid

Can someone please help me identify the issue and provide a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are trying to assign an Excel Range *(More than one cell)*, into a single column:

- `oSheet.Range("A4")` will return `A4` entire column
- `oSheet.Range("A8:A19")` will return all cells in this range `A8:A19`

Instead of using `Range` property:

```
Output0Buffer.OrgName = oSheet.Range("A4").Value
```

You should use `Cells` property to read a specific cell:

```
Output0Buffer.OrgName = oSheet.Cells(4,1).Value
```

To read more about Cells property you can refer to the following documentation:

- [Worksheet.Cells property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)
- [How to convert Excel column numbers into alphabetical characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/convert-excel-column-numbers)